# How to switch tabs in a browser Web Extension

Tags: javascript, browser-extension, browser-tab, web-extension, safari-web-extension

As title states ^

In these docs, there's a lot of support for working with tabs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs

Including moving tabs around, deleting them, duplicating, reloading, executing javascript in the tab, etc. But I don't see anything that allows me to focus a given a tab.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

`tabs.update(tabId, {highlighted:true})`

Answer (score 0):

```js
browser.tabs.update(tabId, { active: true })
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/update

Setting `highlighted` to `true` will not necessarily switch tabs.
For example, a tab already highlighted in Firefox will not become the active tab.

> `highlighted` (optional):
>
> `boolean`. Adds or removes the tab from the current selection. If `true` and the tab is not highlighted, it will become active by default.
>
> If you only want to highlight the tab without activating it, Firefox accepts setting `highlighted` to `true` and `active` to `false`. Other browsers may activate the tab even in this case.